# RSS/XML parsing remove html tag in <description>?

Tags: php, xml, parsing, rss, simple-html-dom

i'm parsing this rss site with simple html dom.

but the result in tag `<description>`, containing html tag .

```
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<description>
<br><table border=0 width= valign=top cellpadding=2
cellspacing=7><tr><td valign=top><a
href="http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=T&ct=us/0-0&fd=R&url=http://www.raleighchronicle.com/2006072105.html&cid=1108150860&ei=hUzBRO_JMpe2aInH 4PsB">Truck
Driver Wins $100,000 In Lottery; <b>NC</bPowerball
Winners</a><br><font size=-1><font color=#6f6f6f>Raleigh
Chronicle,&nbsp;NC&nbsp;-</font<nobr>2 hours
ago</nobr></font><br><font size=-1>REIDSVILLE -- According to the
<b>NC</bLottery Commission, when Dennis Mebane collected his prize
this week from a winning $100,000 instant scratch-off ticket, he
<b>...</b</font><br></table>
</description>
</channel>
</rss>
```

this is my dom parsing, im using strip_tags but didn't work

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html = file_get_html($data);
$content = $html->find('description',0)->plaintext;
echo strip_tags($content);
```

how to remove all html tag ?

thanks before :)

Comment: tried strip_tags()? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: You could use a regular expression to remove all the html tags. Except, you would also need to parse `<br>` as newlines... I also see a broken tag (</font), that could make the regular expression fail.

Comment: @RakeshSharma strip tag is not working,

Comment: @Colandus how combine with simple html dom, I had already tried, but it did not work